# Is it possible declare type optionally in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for something like this...

```
type B = a ? 'apple' | 'grape' | 'orange' : 'apple' | 'grape'; // Of course, ERROR!

const x = (a: boolean, b: B) => console.log('foo')
```

How can I implement this? Is it possible in Typescript?

Comment: I think you're looking for [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed. To do this, you'll need to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html). Like this:

```
type Type1 = "apple" | "grape" | "orange";
type Type2 = "apple" | "grape";

const x = <A extends boolean>(a: A, b: A extends true ? Type1 : Type2) =>
  console.log("foo");

x(false, "orange"); // error
x(true, "orange"); // no error
```